# Как разбить JFrame случайным образом на чёрн-бел клетки

Tags: java

Поле 3*3 клетки, состоит из чёрных и белых размещённых случайным образом

Не могу разобраться во взаимосвязи между окном JFrame, его методом paint(), и своим классом Map
Просьба помочь разобраться или направить в нужную литературу или исправить мой код или сказать как надо

```
public class Map extends JFrame{

private static int[][] level = new int[3][3];
private static int size = 40; 

public void FillLevel(){
    int[][] level = GetLevel();
    Random r = new Random();
    for (int i = 0; i < level.length; i++)
        for (int j = 0; j < level.length; j++)
            level[i][j] = r.nextInt(1);
    SetLevel(level);
    Print(level);
}

public void SetLevel(int[][] l){
    Map.level = l.clone();
}

public static int[][] GetLevel(){
    return Map.level;
}

public static int GetSize(){
    return Map.size;
}

public void paint(Graphics g){
    int x = 0, y = 0;
    int[][] level = GetLevel();
    for (int i = 0; i < level.length; i++)
        for (int j = 0; j < level.length; j++){
            x = j * GetSize();
            y = i * GetSize();
            if (level[i][j] == 0)
                g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
            else
                g.setColor(Color.WHITE);
            g.fillRect(x, y, GetSize(), GetSize());
        }
}

public static void Print(int[][] mas){
    for (int i = 0; i < mas.length; i++){
        for (int j = 0; j < mas.length; j++)
            System.out.print(mas[i][j] + '\t');
        System.out.println();
    }
}

public static void main(String args[]){
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("Test");
    frame.setBounds(100, 100, 400, 400);
    frame.setVisible(true);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.paint(frame.getGraphics());
}
```

}

Мой код рисует просто серое окно

Comment: рисует просто серое окно, потому что в методе main с которого и начинается работа программы нет ни одной строки которая вызывала бы твои методы класса Map

Comment: изменил с:
frame.paint(frame.getGraphics())
на:
Map.paints(frame.getGraphics())
и поправил, соответственно, имя метода внутри класса Map на paints()
Никаких изменений